# How to fix a completely different output using .replace() and .substring()?

Tags: javascript, string

I just created a script that (in theory) replaces the number "9" with " Nein " (no racism intended), and it makes a completely different output than expected.

Instead of printing "Nein Nein Nein" from and input "999", it prints "undefined Nein 99 Nein 9".

```
var inputString;
var outputString;

function submit() {
    inputString = document.getElementById('input').value;
    for (i = 0; i <= inputString.length; i++) {
        outputString += inputString.replace(9, ' Nein ');
        document.getElementById('outputP').innerHTML = outputString;
        inputString = inputString.substring(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first time you use `outputString += `, it is undefined because it has never been defined before. Seems that you intended it to be a string, so perhaps at the top define it as an empty string when you declare it (i.e., `var outputString = "";`)

Comment: The easiest way is to use a regular expression `"Your string".replace(/9/g, ' Nein ')` It will replace al occurrences for 9

Comment: After undefined, the program added it a ' Nein 99' (999 with the first replace), and a ' Nein 9' (99 with the 2nd replace). It should have a final Nein somewhere but maybe the output cut it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're intent on looping, I'd recommend making use of the iterator in the loop and doing the replacement character-by-character.

```js
var inputString;
var outputString = '';

function submit() {
    inputString = document.getElementById('input').value;
    for (let i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
        outputString += inputString[i].replace(9, ' Nein ');
    }
    
    document.getElementById('outputP').innerHTML = outputString;
}

submit();
```

```html
<input id="input" value="999" />
<p id="outputP"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```js
function submit() {
    inputString = document.getElementById('input').value;
    outputString = inputString.replace(/9/g, ' Nein');
    document.getElementById('outputP').innerHTML = outputString;
}
```

```html
<input id='input' />

<button onclick="submit()">submit</button>

<div id='outputP'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you're redefining `inputString` within your for loop.

I am not clear on what you are trying to do with the redefinition of `inputString`, but here is an example of doing what you want with the `replace` method. I think the reason you  ended up with the `for` loop is because you missed the `/g` flag:

```js
const inputString = '999';
console.log(inputString.replace(/9/g, ' Nein '));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

`outputString` is not initialized, therefore it is `undefined`. The first concatenation will therefore be done with the string value of `undefined` aka `"undefined"`.

Instead of looping through the string and replacing one by one, you could use a simple regular expression to do the job :

```
function nineToNein(input){
  return input.replace(/9/g, " Nein ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use inputString[index].

```js
    var inputString = "999";
    var outputString = "";
    var n = inputString.length;
    for(var i = 0; i< n; i++) {
     outputString += inputString[i].replace(9, ' Nein ');
    }
    console.log(outputString);
```